# robot - Paramiko package not executing command 'set management cwmp enable on' in windows while saving some configuration in remote host using ssh

Tags: python, robotframework, paramiko

I used `pexpect` in windows  for SSH. It didn't work. So I installed `paramiko`. With `paramiko` I'm able to login to the remote host .But I couldn't run the commands after 'conf' command. When I run the command 'set management cwmp enable on' it throws an error:

> unrecognized command.

When run on `putty` it will be like:

```
name:xyz

pass:xyz


>satus
#writes status
>magic

>UNLOCKED>

>UNLOCKED>conf
>>set management cwmp enable on
>>save

*configuration saved*
```

## the above should appear.

Python code:

```
 import paramiko

 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 ssh.connect( '192.168.2.254',port = 22, username = 'xyz', password = 'xyz')
 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command( 'status' )
 output = stdout.readlines()
 print "\n".join(output)
 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('magic')
 output1 = stdout.readlines()
 print output1
 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('conf')
 output1 = stdout.readlines()
 print  output1
 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('set management cwmp enable on')
 output1 = stdout.readlines()
 print output1
```

OUTPUT:

```
#after executing conf command
```

### Unrecognized command

2. I unable to find equivalent command like "'expect' in pexpect" in paramiko?